# Is there anyway to make google assistant's speech recognition better recognise words used in my dialogflow agent?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using Dialogflow to create a chatbot that can be used on google assistant. However the speech recognition often mis-recognizes the intended word. Example, when I say the word "seal", it recognizes the spoken word wrongly as "shield".

Is there any way to "train" or make google assistant better recognize a word?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited amount of words that you would like to improve upon, then using Dialogflow's [entities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzdL6GxJ_WY) would be an option. For instance, if you are trying to recognize certain animals. You can create a set of animals as entities and set the intent to look for an animal entity in the user input.

Besides this option I don't know of any other things to improve the speech itself, you could [train](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/training) Dialogflow to map both "seal" and "shield" to your desired intent, but that doesn't change the actual word, it will still be shield.

For any other improvements to the speech recognition, I'm afraid you will have to wait for updates from Google to their algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out there is a new beta function in dialogflow that should help.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/speech-adaptation

Edit:
However does not work with Actions on google.